# Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Tags: php, wp-query, wpdb

In the code below (from my functions.php), I'm attempting to create an array of items from the wp_postmeta table where the meta_key is "_wp_attached_file". I'm getting an error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object

What's wrong with the query?

```
$excludeImages = array();
$excludeImages = $wpdb->query("SELECT meta_value 
                              FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
                              WHERE meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'");

array_push($excludeImages);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi **@Scott B:**

Did you remember to include a `global $wpdb;` in your code, like so?

```
global $wpdb;
$excludeImages = array();
$excludeImages = $wpdb->query("SELECT meta_value 
                              FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
                              WHERE meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'");

array_push($excludeImages);
```

Comment: @Scott B - Can't tell you how often I've been stuck on that very issue... :)